# Supply video buffers during play

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, core-video

Is there a way to play a video where the buffers are supplied through a callback during play time?

Comment: Maybe AVAssetReader is what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about AVAssetReader?